# Spring Data / Hibernate - don't automatically open JDBC connection before checking L2 cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, caching

We use Spring Data JPA and have successfully configured L2 entity and query caches. What still bothers me though is the fact that Hibernate always opens a JDBC connection before checking the L2 cache. This sometimes causes issues (too many open connections) due to a very busy database.

Is there a way to make Hibernate only open a JDBC connection after a L2 cache miss?

Just to clarify, here are the session metrics:

```
i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
    1716707 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    236767 nanoseconds spent performing 1 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

So even though there was absolutely no query performed on the database, a JDBC connection was still opened.

Comment: Are you using an explicit transaction around this operation? If so, the transaction callbacks probably require that a physical connection exists.

Comment: You can debug into `org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl#acquireConnectionIfNeeded` to understand what acquires the connection. If you think this can be improved, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. As far as I know Spring Data JPA methods have a `@Transactional` by default with `read-only` enabled where applicable. So this might very well be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to pointers given by Christian Beikov I've found out that the jdbc connection is necessary for the transaction around the operation.

It was the `@Transactional` that is enabled for methods in the default Spring Data JPA repository implementation. Overriding one of these methods and leaving the annotation away causes everything to work solely on the cache without any jdbc connection involved.

Answer (score 0):

Although removing `@Transactional` might appear to solve your issue it actually isn't. You want to delay the acquisition of the connection for this you would need to do some additional configuration

1. Set `spring.jpa.open-in-view=false` this disables Open Session In View
2. Set `spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false`, this will optimize Hibernate to not set this (performance of your app)

This should stop Hibernate from actually getting a physical connection to the point when it actually needs to. Even when inside the transaction (as it now not needs to check the connection for auto-commit).

I'm assuming you are using Spring Boot, if not at least set the `autoCommit` property of your datasource to `false` should already fix this (if you are on a recent Spring (Boot) version!).

See also [this explanation](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/) by Vlad Mihalcea (the goto source for JPA/Hibernate related stuff :) ).

Comment: Thanks! This would indeed be a much cleaner solution, I will give it a go... The first item is already taken care of, so that leaves number 2.

Comment: Just to be clear, this would need to be done in addition to removing `@Transactional`?

Comment: No, instead of removing the `@Transactional`... Setting this will enable hibernate to delay the acquisition of a connection up until the point it really needs to operate on a `Connection`. Which would be when executing the query, which wouldn't happen if there was a cache hit.

Comment: Ok. Well, it doesn't seem to work for me. Behavior is the same as in the opening post. I'm running Spring Boot 2.7.3 with no hibernate version overrides and also adding `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true` makes no difference.

Comment: Weird as that property should be set automatically when you set the auto-commit to `false` on hikari (I do assume you are using that and use a spring configured one and not your own, the same for the JPA stuff). Could you include your configuration (properties or overridden) in your question?

Comment: Forget it. The JPA stuff is in the way here :(. Spring eagerly gets the connection and tries to enforce the `readOnly` on the connection. Which is what the `findById` etc. on the `SimpleJpaRepository`. You could get around this by using a `BeanPostProcssor` to set the `prepareConnection` property on the `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` and then set the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.handling_mode=DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_HOLD`. Which is actually being set when the `prepareConnection` is `true` which is a bit counter intuitive.